# What is the right preposition after "report"?

Tags: prepositions

"He will report into Charles." or "He will report to Charles." ?
"He will report into the Collectorate." or "He will report to the Collectorate." ?

Comment: *Report* takes a normal indirect object with *to* or *for*, as in: "Jim reported *to* Charles *for* duty."  I have never seen any usage `report into` myself.

Answer (score 8):

Report *to* is normally used when the subject is a singular entity.

> You will report to the CEO
>
> This position reports to the board.

Report "into" can be used when describing when a person reports to a *position* (esp. multiple positions) in a company, rather than the person in that position:

> You will be reporting into the Regional Sales Head's team, with a dotted line to the Business Unit Head.

Although generally speaking this usage is less common, and it's normally easier to just use "to".

Report *into* also more commonly used to describe what the report is *about*:

> The report into the botched military operation was delivered to the President by the Joint Chiefs.
>
> My report into the American Revolutionary War is due on Tuesday.

It is also used to show insertion of a report *into* some portfolio, or rendering the report into a specific format:

> We posted the report *into* the website's "reports" section.
>
> We saved the report *into* a PDF.
>
> We added the report into our proposal.

Comment: There is also the phrasal verb *report in*, to make one's presence known. *Report into* is rather rare, at least in North America, but constructions like *report in to [your supervisor]* are common.